# column-span function, how to return width of column in current grid not global one?

Tags: singularitygs

I would like to use the "column-span" function to return the width of the grid column, but without including a specific grid in this function, the global "grid" variable is used.

As I'm creating a mobile first design, the global grid variable is set to 4, but with breakpoint, using "add-grid", the div should include 16 columns at this specific grid. column-span ignores this, so it returns the column as If the grid is 4 column, not 16.

Comment: Can you recreate this in http://sassmeister.com/? Be aware it's using Singularity 1.2's code, which changes `$grids: add-grid()` to `@include add-grid()` for all items, including the starting grid.

Comment: Here it is, I did my best to recreate the idea in the simplest way possible: [link](http://sassmeister.com/gist/9198641)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the way `add-*` works in Singularity is that instead of writing different code automatically for you, it changes the default when inside a matching `breakpoint` media query. The reason Singularity doesn't automatically write all of the changes for you is it has no way of knowing how you want something to change between different grid definitions and instead of guessing and making a mess of things, it requires you to specify exactly how you want things to change.

I have [updated your link](http://sassmeister.com/gist/9201223) to show how calling `column-span` again inside of an appropriate `breakpoint` mixin does in fact use the default you've defined.

Comment: That was really simple and really made me understand how things work in singularity better, thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. I realize this answer is a bit vague for "matching `breakpoint` media query". The media query doesn't need to be exactly the same, it just needs to fall inside of the expected result, so `@include add-grid(5 at 400px)` would be used for `@include breakpoint(423px) {}` as it matches the `min-width` as well.